# Woocommerce and Pricing deals plugin total price update with AJAX

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using Pricing deals pro plugin and i have a custom theme which displays a custom cart on shop page.
I've created ajax functions for cart items update and cart price update:

For the item update i'm using this functionality:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_upate-cartitem-filter', 'prefix_update_cart_item' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_upate-cartitem-filter', 'prefix_update_cart_item' );

function prefix_update_cart_item (){

    $product_key = $_POST[ 'itemkey' ];
    $item_quantity = $_POST[ 'itemamount' ];

    global $woocommerce;
    wc()->cart->set_quantity($product_key, $item_quantity, true);

    die();
}
```

To get cart totals i'm using this one:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_upate-carttotal-filter', 'prefix_update_cart_total' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_upate-carttotal-filter', 'prefix_update_cart_total' );

function prefix_update_cart_total(){

    global $woocommerce;    

    $total_price = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();

    echo $total_price;
}
```

When i'm updating the product using standard AJAX i'm getting the totals without the pricing deals plugin calculations, only after page refresh i'm getting the price after the deal. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your cart after a property change (such as price or item quantity), you might want to take a look at this:

https://gist.github.com/mikaelz/f41e29c6a99a595602e4